# Typescript type checking error how to fix in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
const [fetchJobTitlesCall, { data }] = useLazyQuery<Jobtitles, JobtitlesVariables>(JobTitlesQuery)
useEffect(() => {
    fetchJobTitlesCall({ variables: { keyword: 'Dev' } })
}, [fetchJobTitlesCall, data])

return (
            <Autocomplete
              onChange={(event, value) => dispatchJobTitlesFilter(value)}
              multiple
              id="tags-outlined"
              options={data?.jobTitles} // this line throwing error
              getOptionLabel={option => option.name + ` (${option.totalApplicants})`} // this line throwing error
              filterSelectedOptions
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  onChange={event => fetchJobTitles(event.target.value)}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Search Job Title"
                  placeholder="Search Job Title"
                />
              )}
            />
)
```

The error I get is:

> Type 'Jobtitles_jobTitles | undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'unknown[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'unknown[]'.

Can anyone explain why I am getting the error?

Comment: As stated, the `data.jobTitles` can be either of type `Jobtitles_jobTitles` or `undefined`. If You are sure it can never be undefined try using `data!.jobTitles`. Also providing fallback data might help. Like `data.jobTitles || []`. I hope the comment is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like typescript wants you to pass some kind of variable having data type other than undefined. The issue seems to be with

> options={data?.jobTitles}

What it essentially does is it will check for key "jobTitles" in data and assign it's content to options if it exist, otherwise assign undefined(which is not the right thing in this case)

```
const [fetchJobTitlesCall, { data }] = useLazyQuery<Jobtitles, JobtitlesVariables>(JobTitlesQuery)
useEffect(() => {
    fetchJobTitlesCall({ variables: { keyword: 'Dev' } })
}, [fetchJobTitlesCall, data])

return (
            <Autocomplete
              onChange={(event, value) => dispatchJobTitlesFilter(value)}
              multiple
              id="tags-outlined"
              options={data.jobTitles ? data.jobTitles : {}} // Modified code
              getOptionLabel={option => option.name + ` (${option.totalApplicants})`} // this should be automatically fixed
              filterSelectedOptions
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  onChange={event => fetchJobTitles(event.target.value)}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Search Job Title"
                  placeholder="Search Job Title"
                />
              )}
            />
)
```

Comment: nothing really changes, the error still remains after changes u suggested!

Comment: try this
options={data.jobTitles ? data.jobTitles : []}

Comment: Have you tried the solution @Davit proposed in comment to your question?

Comment: well I dont think there is any much more helpful data than the one I provided. others are just info about path of file and few unrelated info, thnx anyhow for trying to solve my problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213684/discussion-between-faizan-mustafa-and-lulzim).